# How to manually activate/deactivate Subscriptions to an Azure Service Bus

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, subscription

I have been given client software to support, with all that entails.  Right now there is an Azure Service Bus and it has 4 subscriptions, dev, prod, etc.

Currently the old azure site (manage.windowsazure.com) allows you to toggle activation on each subscription.  Most of the time this is being accomplished via a script that needs to turn off it's related subscription when it runs and then turns it back on.  Sometime things break and they need to be turned on/off manually.

I have not found a way to do this on the new site (portal.azure.com) and turning off the whole bus is not an option (or not a very good one) since it would be turning off the prod feed on a dev update.

I personally don't have access to this client on the old site (yet) but regardless, in August editing the bus in the old site will be removed and limited to the new site (announced yesterday).

Is there a way that I haven't found? Are they going to add a way? Am I going to have to write a script that I can run from Azure to do this, and if so are there good examples I could follow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the desktop Service Bus Explorer to Disable a Topic or a Subscription.

See picture below:

[image]

You can get the code from here if you don't have it already:

https://github.com/paolosalvatori/ServiceBusExplorer

Also the compiled version of the Service Bus Explorer:

https://github.com/paolosalvatori/ServiceBusExplorer/releases

Comment: Thanks, I'm looking into using this!  If I get it to work, I'll mark it as answered.

Comment: Or get the release straight from: https://github.com/paolosalvatori/ServiceBusExplorer/releases 

Comment: Yes, that is what I needed!  Thanks!  and the link from Sean Feldman was useful too